# HTML in Anki cards

Tags: html, anki

I'm want to display some image (.jpg) file from the local storage on each Anki card of particular note type. The code below shows the image on any browser:

```
<img src="file:///path/to/your/image.jpg" alt="Image alternate text" style="height:100px;width:100px">
```

Any attempts to load jpg file to Anki card do not produce any result. While using

```html
    <video width="620" height="640" controls="controls">
    <source src="file:///Users/..../small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
```

I can access any mp4 file on my local drive and it's shown in the card as expected. Is the way to access image (.jpg/png) files from the local storage the same way? What is the trick in Anki cards? Now I need it only for the Anki desktop version. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Media files referenced in cards should be located within Anki's data folder. You shouldn't use absolute paths but only filenames within a "collection.media" folder in your Anki data folder.

In short you should:

- use `<img src="XXX.jpg">` code in your cards (pay attention to avoid name collisions),
- import file having "Allow HTML in fields" checked,
- put XXX.jpg in Anki's "collection.media" (under Anki in your user's documents folder)

See https://apps.ankiweb.net/docs/manual.html#_importing_media for further details.

Answer (score 3):

A straight-forward solution here is to (while the card editor is open) **drag-and-drop the desired media** from the source folder into a card field. By doing so, the media file will be (1) copied to your Anki's **media.collection folder** and (2) the necessary **HTML mark-up** will be **auto-generated** for you. You will see that the HTML mark-up on your cards correspond with the accepted answer above.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17762808)

Comment: @EJoshuaS Updated according to your feedback. Was this useful?